# Adding data to an existing Excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I need to add some data to an existing Excel file. My script only adds data to a new sheet. When I try to write into an existing sheet (e.g. `template`) of my existing file, it creates two different sheets (e.g. `template` and `template 1`). How can I prevent this?

```
precios_read = pd.read_excel('Precios_{}.xls'.format(auth2), sheet_name='Precios')

book = load_workbook('Template_sugerencia.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Template_sugerencia.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = writer
precios_read.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='template', startcol=12, startrow=5, index=False, merge_cells = True)
Recom.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='template', startcol=0, startrow=5, index=False, merge_cells = True)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Use `from openpyxl.utils.pandas.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

For XLSX, `pandas.ExcelWriter.book` should be an `openpyxl.workbook.Workbook`, which you actually have but do not use anywhere:

```
book = load_workbook('Template_sugerencia.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Template_sugerencia.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
precios_read.to_excel(...)
```

If you don't set `writer.book = book`, pandas [will make a new one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d6fe1940a5d7ea10624e1cc871a6eef13f32b382/pandas/io/excel.py#L989) implicitly.